# Растягивающийся DIV по мере заполнения

Tags: html, css

В общем есть это в html

```
   <div class="page">
     <div id="content">

     </div>
     <div id="footer">

     </div>

   </div>
```

Как сделать, что бы при наполнении "content" див футера сдвигался следом за ним, т.е контент при заполнении толкал футер в низ?

```
.page
{
    position:absolute;
    width:1200px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-600px;
    height:100%;
    min-height:940px;
}
.page #content
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#FFF;
    top:228px;
}
```

Comment: Вы бы еще css показали бы ), потому что по хтмл видно, что футер пойдет после блока контента контента)

Comment: `.page #content{position:absolute;}` - это уберите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.page
{
    width:1200px; // такую ширину лучше не задавать по умолчанию
    min-width: 960px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 500px; // установим тестовую высоту чтобы увидеть что footer двигается вниз
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid; // border для проверки как стоят блоки
}

#content
{
    margin: 10px 0px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border: 1px solid; // border для проверки как стоят блоки

}

#footer
{
    border: 1px solid; // border для проверки как стоят блоки
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Да ничего не нужно делать, это будет автоматически происходить! По крайней мере в ситуации, которую Вы привели.

Делайте `position: relative;` для контента.